# build web application programmatically

Tags: java, web, compilation

i want to compile web application with lots of imports and dependency pro-grammatically i can use javax.tools

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(System.in , System.out ,System.err, "D:/data/jeeViews/projects/seds/vcvd/main/com/vcvd/servlet/Dispatcher.java");
```

the problem is that won't import class and throws a `ClassNotFound` exception.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Also post printStackTrace here.

Answer (score 1):

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(System.in , System.out ,System.err, "/home/visruth/Desktop/Sample.java");
```

Sample.java :

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String... args) {

    System.out.println("Hello world");

    }

}
```

The above code works for me.

Make sure that the path `"D:/data/jeeViews/projects/seds/vcvd/main/com/vcvd/servlet/Dispatcher.java"` you have given is valid.
Please post code in `Dispatcher.java`. Because, if it refers other classes inside it may also make this exception. For instance, suppose there is also an another *Another.java* file exists in the same location where *Sample.java* exists. If the above *Sample.java* is modified as follows may make this exception on `Another another = new Another();` because, it refers *Another class* from the class path.

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String... args) {

    // makes exception as it is not in the class path.
    // to avoid exception make it available in the class path.
    Another another = new Another();

    System.out.println("Hello world");

    }

}
```

Another.java :

```
public class Another {

//codes........

}
```

The better solution is to use a *build tool* like [ant](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_build_files.htm).

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFound` exception is basically what it says.

It can't find the required file to compile.

This means one of two things

1. You are pointing to the wrong location (hopefully not)
2. You are using a Package or other Class of an uncompiled file. For example: If you use Package `C` Class `A` you have to make sure Package `C` class `A` is compiled before compiling your class.

(This holds true for ANY class you import)

Comment: thank one of the problem was the one you mentioned another was invalid classPath location usually eclipe do the hard works

Comment: Eclipse tends to check the path of the `.java` files sometimes it doesn't realize if they're not compiled yet which causes the problem